# DropDownListFor onchange but for same value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to trigger an onchange event, even if the value they select is the same as before. I have tried onselect, but it does not trigger at all. And onchange does not trigger if value is the same. Is there any other patterns I could use to make this possible?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMarkdownDate, Model.ValidDatesSelectList, new{onchange = "LoadGridData(this);" })
```

Comment: which is correct right ? nothing has changed and no trigger

Comment: correct, however I'm wondering if there is some other way to get this behavior.

Comment: Can you use the onclick event?

Comment: The onclick does not behave correctly because as soon as you click anywhere on the dropdown it will trigger before something is selected, it needs to trigger once something is chosen. mousedown does not work either since you click once to only open the dropdown, causing it to trigger.

Comment: Can you add the event with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using JQuery:

```
var go = false;
$('#SelectedMarkdownDate').on('click',function() {//on click
    if (go) {//if go

        var date = $('#SelectedMarkdownDate option:selected').text();

        LoadGridData(date);

        go = false;//switch off

    } else { go = true; }//if !go, switch on
}).on('blur', function () { go = false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you answered your question, however I already made a fiddle so here it is.

you can use the onClick event with blur to tell whether or not the dropdown is open, when you select the same item it gives you an alert just to demonstrate that it recognizes the event.

https://jsfiddle.net/Anon_E_Mustard/yoxs0gk8/

```
<script>
  var dropboxOpen = false,
      oldItem     = null;
      counter       = 0;
  function onClick(e) {
      if (dropboxOpen) {
          if (oldItem && oldItem === e.target.value) {
              alert("same selected")
          }
          oldItem = e.target.value;
          dropboxOpen = false;
      }else{
        dropboxOpen = true;
      }

  }

  function onBlur(e){
    dropboxOpen = false;
  }
</script>


<select onclick="onClick(event)" onblur="onBlur(event)">
  <option value="volvo">volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">saab</option>
  <option value="opel">opel</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
</select>
```